# Breeze-Unreferenced Entity in Manager

Tags: breeze, single-page-application, hottowel

I am developing a Single Page App using Hot Towel Template, using breeze...and I have come across a peculiar problem, and I am unable to figure out the internal working which causes it...

I have a Programmes table, and the Programmes table has a foreign key to Responses, so the structure of Programmes is:

```
Id, ResponseID, Name and Date
```

and the Page has Name and Date, the foreign comes from RouteData.
and for one ResponseId in Programmes table, I want to save only on Programme.

So, when user comes to this page, it check the Programmes table that if it has an Entry for that particular Response Id, if yes, it goes in Edit case and if not it goes to Add a new entry case.

To achieve this, what I am doing is below:

```
var objTempProgramme = ko.observable();   
var objProgramme = ko.observable();

function activate(routeData) {
       responseId = parseInt(routeData.responseId);

       // Create a Programme Entity
       objProgramme(datacontext.createProgramme());

       // Fill in a Temporary Observable with Programmes data
       datacontext.getEntitiesDetailsByRelativeId('responseID', responseId , 'Programmes', objTempProgramme, true).then(function(){
                // Check if Programmes Exists
                if (objTempProgramme() != null && objTempProgramme() != undefined) {
                // What I am doing here is filling my Programmes Entity with data coming from database (if it is there)                    
                objProgramme(objTempProgramme());
                } else {
                // The Else Part assigns the Foreign Key (ResponseId) to my Entity Created above
                objProgramme().responseID(responseId);
                }
       });
}
```

In datacontext.js:

```
    var createProgramme = function () {
        return manager.createEntity(entityNames.programme);
    }

    var getEntitiesDetailsByRelativeId = function (relativeIdName, relativeId, lookupEntity, observable, forceRefresh) {
    var query = entityQuery.from(lookupEntity).where(relativeIdName, "==", relativeId);
        return executeGetQuery(query, observable, forceRefresh);
    };
```

Now when I call **manager.saveChanes** on my page, I would Expect objProgramme to be saved, in any case, be it edit or be it save, 
but what breeze is doing here is that though it is filling objTempProgramme in objProgramme, but it is also leaving the entity objProgramme unreferenced with its manager, so that when I call save, it tries to save that entity too (2 entities in total, objProramme and one unreferenced one), but that entity does not have foreign key set and it fails..but my question is why?

**Assigning one entity to another does not mean all its properties get assigned to another? And why is that unreferenced entity present?**

Comment: I am struggling to understand the question. Part of my problem is that you've hidden essential information behind your `datacontext` methods and the `fillProgrammes` method. And what are `objProgramme` and `objTempProgramme`? Are they viewmodel observables that hold entities? What is a 'relativeId' and how does that relate to a `responseId`? I don't want a huge amount of code to wade through. But I do need to know how you are creating entities and assigning related entities (or their ids). Perhaps a simpler example with all code would help me understand.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble Ward..I have removed the redundant code..and added datacontext functions, but still if you feel it is insufficient, let me explain a bit...at the page activation an entity objProgramme is created and then I execute a GET query to fetch any records in the database based on ResponseId, if it exists, I simply equate my objProgramme entity to my temporary observable that has data, objTempProgramme....but after this equality operation, when I try to save changes, manager tries to save 2 entities...I guess the one I created at activate..

Comment: ...but was'nt that entity filled with valid data?...why does manager have two entities?... am I doing anything wrong?...I know best approach would be to create entity only after checking that if objTempProgramme is null...but still I am curious about the internal working...Thanks.